# What is the composition of camel urine. Does it contain any particularly toxic substance?

Tags: toxicity

I'd like to know the composition of camel urine. Furthermore, I'd like to know if it contains any known toxins.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.ijpsonline.com/articles/characterization-and-determination-of-major-bioactive-acids-in-camel-urine-using-gas-chromatography-massspectrometry.html?view=mobile) at the Indian Journal for Pharmaceutical Sciences' website,

> The chemical composition of camel urine has been reported to contain organic nitrogen, ammonia, urea, creatinine, creatine, hippuric acid and chloride.

Comment: hippuric acid?  cameluric, surely?